# Managing Flask session while using stripe

Tags: session, flask, stripe-payments

The user completes a form and based on that completion the user gets its product.
In the form I have a hidden field that has a random string generated each time the page is accessed, based on that hidden input field value I set a session: `session["session_id"]=form.session_field.data`, and insert the form data into database.

I have set up a webhook that captures when the payment has succeded, so now I have to update the order in my database based on that `session["session_id"]`, but stripe creates a new session in the webhook route and `session_id` key is no longer available. I get this error while executing the following code:

```
@app.route('/stripe_webhook', methods=['POST'])
def stripe_webhook():
print('WEBHOOK CALLED')
print(session["session_id"])
```

error: `line 124, in stripe_webhook print(session["session_id"])`

```
 AttributeError: 'SecureCookieSession' object has no attribute 'session_id'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `metadata` in stripe session object to store that data. More info here: https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/object